# Optimized Chernoff Bound

Tags: probability, random-variables, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to find the optimized Chernoff bound of a sum of i.i.d. discrete random variables X<sub>i</sub>, 0$\leq$ i < n, with support {-1,0,1}.  I also know that pX<sub>0</sub>(1) > pX<sub>0</sub>(-1).  However, I'm not sure if I optimized the bound correctly over t.

My attempt looks like this:

I computed the moment generating function of X<sub>0</sub> as

M<sub>X</sub><sub>0</sub>(t) = E[$e^{tX0}$] = $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{tX0(k)}$pX<sub>0</sub>(k) = $e^{t(-1)}$pX<sub>0</sub>(-1) + $e^{t(1)}$pX<sub>0</sub>(1) + pX<sub>0</sub>(0)

I then found the moment generating function of the sum of the random variables from 0 to n-1 by multiplying their respective moment generating functions:

M<sub>S</sub><sub>n</sub> = M[$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$ X<sub>i</sub>] = M<sub>X</sub><sub>0</sub> M<sub>X</sub><sub>1</sub> ... M<sub>X</sub><sub>n-1</sub> = [$e^{-t}$pX<sub>0</sub>(-1) + $e^{t}$pX<sub>0</sub>(1)+pX<sub>0</sub>(0)]$^{n}$

The optimized Chernoff bound for Pr[S<sub>n</sub>$\le$a] is given by

Pr[S<sub>n</sub>$\le$a] $\le$ min $e^{ta}$ $\prod _ { i = 0 } ^ n E[e^{-tXi}]$ 
Pr[S<sub>n</sub>$\le$0] $\le$ [$e^{-t}$pX<sub>0</sub>(-1) + $e^{t}$pX<sub>0</sub>(1) + pX<sub>0</sub>(0)]$^{n}$

Letting c1 = pX<sub>0</sub>(-1) and c2 = pX<sub>0</sub>(1), I then minimize the above expression by taking its derivative and setting it equal to 0 to obtain

-c1$e^{-t}$ + c2$e^{t}$ = 0 
c2$e^{t}$ = c1$e^{-t}$ 
$e^{2t}$ = c1/c2 
2t = ln(c1/c2) 
t = $\frac 1 { 2 }$ln$\frac {c1} {c2}$

Substituting the optimized value of t into the generic Chernoff bound I obtain

Pr(S<sub>n</sub>$\leq$0) $\leq$ [($\frac {pX0(-1)} {pX0(1)}$) $^{-1/2}$ pX<sub>0</sub>(-1) + ($\frac {pX0(-1)} {pX0(1)}$) $^{1/2}$ pX<sub>0</sub>(1) + pX<sub>0</sub>(0)]$^n$

Is this the correct optimized Chernoff bound for Pr[S<sub>n</sub>$\le$0]?  Thanks for your help and insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation seems to be correct but your final value of t  is less than 0 as probability of getting a 1 is greater than getting a  -1 as you stated earlier. So you can't  use that value if you actually try to minimize the expression you have to put t equals to 0 which will  be of no use.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  Does this mean there is no minimization and hence no bound if the probability of getting a 1 is greater than getting a -1?

Comment: It seems like it, although I am not sure whether there's  an approximation  possible or not the hard way where we bring an expression equal to the probability and try to approximate it with some assumptions on n , c1 and c2. But using chernoff we can't  minimize it.